# Track all browsing data

Tags: windows, google-chrome, browser, history, tracking

I want to track all browsing data regardless of which of several web-browser applications (Chrome, Firefox, Opera) is used.

Example

```
URL_Name    No_of_Vists   DurationTime    Timestamp
Youtube          5          500 seconds    11:45 pm
```

How can I do this?

I can get the browser history for each browser and one by one extract the history - but I don't think this is a good solution.

Can I create a local proxy-server and get all browsing details from that?

Comment: I think due to your language barrier it is difficult to understand what you want to do and why

Comment: Do you want to do this from the router or from the browser? Also, what have you tried? And for clarity I assume you're only looking to record your own history

Comment: yes i want to record my own history of all browser.... i tried this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608200/programmatically-acess-google-chrome-history  but here its not a good approach to tracking i need something better that

Comment: have understand what i exactly want?

Comment: I would use https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/54068?hl=en&ref_topic=1753806 - see Turn Web & App Activity on or off

Comment: humm i want to do track all the browsers activity like ...  so i want something common thing like where every request can track easily ..

Comment: And very simple term i want to get all the browsing history from all the browser ..  i tried this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608200/programmatically-acess-google-chrome-history    i want something for common for all browser

Comment: why down vote if you going to down vote so please give answer first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Can I create a proxy server?**

You can configure a local proxy using something like [squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/). It can be made to create the sort of [logs](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/access_log/) you seem to want.

You'll have to post-process them to get session duration. There are tools that calculate that from [common log format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Log_Format) or similar. You might have to write your own since your requirements are specific.

You would have to [configure each web browser to use the proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config) rather than connecting directly to webservers.

Comment: it is possible to configure proxy programmatically into the browsers ?

Comment: @Ankur See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config

Comment: hi thanks for reply i need one more help can you tell me how How i get data from DNS Cache programmatically..?

Comment: @AnkurTripathi - You should ask that as a separate question using the "Ask Question" link at top right of page. Editing your question to replace it wholly with a new different question destroys the value of the Q and answers to future searchers and undermines the objectives of this website - please don't do that. I rolled back your edit.

Comment: Unable to ask question that's by i edit this ..

Comment: Can you allow me to ask one more question ?

Comment: @AnkurTripathi I don't have any special powers on this website, if you have been blocked from asking questions, I don't have any way to undo that (though moderators might). I suggest you  ask about this on [meta.superuser](http://meta.superuser.com/) - there's probably something you can do.

Comment: there i need at least 5 reputation ..

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Read http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/282212 and http://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans. It seems the site expects you to fix your existing question to deal with the reasons people downvoted it or voted to close it.

Comment: if possible can you provide the sample app how could do this.. configure proxy programmatically  ?